# How to update street labels on Billing and Shipping address on Magento 2 checkout payment step

Tags: magento2.4

Just in case if anyone wants to update
shipping address street mutiple fields and
billing address street field labels
please check below
Note - tested on Magento 2.

Am adding this so that someone can get help from the answer . i have answered in the comment below

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if anyone wants to update
shipping address street mutiple fields and
billing address street field labels
please check below
Note - tested on Magento 2.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block;

/**
 * This is plugin which returns collection
 *
 * @author    Tanveer Mohammad <akhil.tanveer@gmail.com>
 * @since     1.0 First time this was introduced.
 * @copyright 1948-2020 akhil
 **/
class LayoutProcessor
{
  /**
   * Get checkout layout content
   *
   * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
   * @param \Closure $proceed
   * @param array $jsLayout
   */
    public function aroundProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayoutResult = $proceed($jsLayout);

        $shippingAddress = &$jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']
        ['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
        ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']
        ['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'];

        unset($shippingAddress['street']['label']);

        // Shipping fields street labels
        $shippingAddress['street']['children']['0']['label'] = __('Address (street and number)');
        $shippingAddress['street']['children']['1']['label'] = __('Floor, door or other');
        $shippingAddress['street']['children']['2']['label'] = __('Address street 3');

        return $jsLayoutResult;
    }

        public function afterProcess(  \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
          array $jsLayout)
          {
              if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
              ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']))
              {

                $billingAddress = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']
                ['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']
                ['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']
                ['form-fields']
                ['children'];
                unset($billingAddress['street']['children']['0']['label']);
                unset($billingAddress['street']['children']['1']['label']);
                unset($billingAddress['street']['children']['2']['label']);

                $billingAddress['street']['children']['0']['label']['0'] = __('Address (street and number)');
                $billingAddress['street']['children']['1']['label']['0'] = __('Floor, door or other');
                $billingAddress['street']['children']['2']['label']['0'] = __('Address street 3');

              }

              return $jsLayout;
          }
}
```

Comment: why used on after and around both?

Comment: Billing address will work only after process
@GohilRajesh observe the first method has logic relevant with shipping and second method with billing.. may be it would work with around on both you and give a try... However I can confirm the above code works for both shipping and billing